# Installing Pillow for Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library

I installed Python 3.7 64 bit on my computer running Windows 10 Home.
I then opened a Windows command prompt and typed easy_install Pillow, and the following happened:

```
C:\Users\Simon>easy_install Pillow
Searching for Pillow
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/Pillow/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/59/edb6fe64a608afc9fd1faf3470774b4131b4be9d40c496b0c144033e249a/Pillow-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=d1722b7aa4b40cf93ac3c80d3edd48bf93b9208241d166a14ad8e7a20ee1d4f3
Best match: Pillow 5.4.1
Processing Pillow-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing Pillow-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl to c:\users\simon\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
Adding Pillow 5.4.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\users\simon\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pillow-5.4.1-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for Pillow
Finished processing dependencies for Pillow
```

That seems to have worked, no ?!
Then in a new python file (do I mean a script ?) in the IDLE editor, I wrote the line

```
from PIL import Image
```

and ran the module.
The shell reported the following:

```
RESTART: C:/FILEPATH REDACTED FOR POSTING ONLINE/Python experiments/python experiment 1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/FILEPATH REDACTED FOR POSTING ONLINE/Python experiments/python experiment 1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
>>>
```

Here I have redacted the file path, but it is just to my folder on the C: drive where I keep my work.

I then tried

```
pip install pillow
```

and got the reply

> Requirement already satisfied: pillow in
>   c:\users\simon\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pillow-5.4.1-py3.7-win-amd64.egg
>   (5.4.1) You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.3 is
>   available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip
>   install --upgrade pip' command.

so I did as suggested, and got the response

> Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (1.4MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 1.3MB/s Installing collected packages: pip   Found existing installation: pip 18.1
>       Uninstalling pip-18.1:
>         Successfully uninstalled pip-18.1 Successfully installed pip-19.0.3

Then I ran my script again, containing just the line

```
from PIL import Image
```

and received the same error message as before, about

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `easy_install` is deprecated. Have you considered using `pip`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have just tried your suggestion, and I've edited my original question to reflect that (it didn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple version of python ?
Make sure you are opening right Python folder and right idle.
Easy install works fine still.
I think the idle you have is from different python folder .
Multiple python installs
Try aNaconda one stop for multiple python and packages

Comment: Thank you Jin. In fact I only have the one version of Python. Good to know that easy install still works ok. Anyway it's working now - it needed to be turned off and on again !!

Answer (score 0):

I closed everything, and started again, and this time it worked ! Sorry everyone - I should have tried switching it off and on again before bothering you !